# Query runs really fast just after analyzing only for 1st attempt, but then slows down considerably in subsequent runs

Tags: database, oracle19c

I am using oracle DB and facing problem while executing the queries.
Query execution is very much slow, it takes nearly 6 mins to execute.

For solving this problem, I analyzed all the tables used in the query.
But I noticed that just after analyzing when I am running the query it executes fast, but it takes time in subsequent runs.

Basically, query execution is only fast just after analyzing all the tables.
I also checked the explain plan of query for both the cases and noticed that there is difference in the explain plan.

I am not understanding what is going wrong, can anyone please help me with this?

For analyzing tables I used query in below format:

```
BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
                                            OwnName           => 'USER2',
                                            TabName           => 'Name of specific tables used in this query',
                                            Estimate_Percent  => 0,
                                            Method_Opt        => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1',
                                            Degree            => 4,
                                            Cascade           => TRUE,
                                            No_Invalidate     => FALSE); 
END;
```

Then for checking if tables are analyzed below query was used:

```
select table_name, last_analyzed from dba_tables where table_name in ('QM_TABLE_NAME1', 'ETC');
```

Below query was used for checking if high frequency gathering is enabled or not:

```
 select dbms_stats.get_prefs('AUTO_TASK_STATUS') from dual;
```

Output of above query is:

```
dbms_stats.get_prefs('AUTO_TASK_STATUS')
----------------------------------------
OFF
```

For generating explain plan I used below queries:

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ ...  
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(9rc0qbr9a5h7a,0,format => 'adaptive allstats last'));
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(9rc0qbr9a5h7a,1,format => 'adaptive allstats last'));
```

GATHER_PLAN_STATISTIC for query with slow execution has below note:

```
Note
-----
   - statistics feedback used for this statement
```

Comment: Regenerate the explain plans using the package `DBMS_XPLAN` and update the question with that output. For example, run queries like `explain plan for select ...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)`, or use a query like `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'your sql_id here'));` The `DBMS_XPLAN` package formats the data better and it includes the important "Note" section at the bottom. That section may explain why the plans change. For example, if the plan is adaptive or uses cardinality feedback, the "Note" section will mention it.

Comment: It would also be helpful to compare the plans and indicate where any differences occur.  Are the "subsequent runs" done immediately after the first run?  Are there large differences in the number/ distribution of the data in the underlying tables (i.e. is there some process that may be doing a large load into one of the tables or is there some table that is supposed to have transient data)/

Comment: Also, although the explain plan hash is static, the *adaptive plan* might change. If your query has an adaptive plan, gather the actual execution plan numbers along with the active adaptive plans. You can do that with queries like `select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'adaptive allstats last'));`. Gathering the right information for complex performance problems can be way more complicated than clicking a button in an IDE. You might need to spend some time reading about some of the `DBMS_XPLAN` features and relevant hints.

Comment: @Rudra Try the `+GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS` method, which will show the actual times and number of rows for each operation. Find the actual times for both runs and then you can find out which operation is taking more time on the second run. (And if you post the results here, please just paste the entire output from that statement, formatted as code to preserve whitespace. Do not mangle it into a table of data and do not exclude any details. Show the whole thing in the format Oracle developers are used to.) If the times do not "add up", that implies a recursive system SQL is taking up the time.

Comment: @Jon Heller Just checked the plan using +GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS method, and noticed that time is getting added up for almost every operation, how am I supposed to proceed further and how can I speed up query execution? Could you please share your point of view on this?

Comment: @Rudra Which operations consume more time on the second run? It might help to know if there's just one operation that is slow and what kind of operation it is. Can you post two of the actual execution plans? Are any of the actual cardinalities different? (This question is interesting, but it's getting confusing because of all the comments. You might want to edit your question and improve the formatting as much as possible, and then more people will be likely to read it.) If this doesn't work, next we'll probably need to drill into the wait events from `GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY.EVENT`.

Comment: @Jon Heller I have edited my question and updated statistic plan for both slow and fast query execution. Please have a look at it and do let me know if any improvement is required. Thanks.

Comment: @Rudra How do you gather statistics? Maybe bad manual stats gathering makes the plan bad, and then high frequency automatic stats gathering fixes it 15 minutes later. Also, add the argument `no_invalidate => false` to your `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_*` function, to force the statistics to immediately take effect. While running your queries, check that statistics change when you expect them: `select table_name, last_analyzed from dba_tables where table_name in ('QM_LOCATION_MAP', 'ETC');` Check if high frequency gathering is enabled: `select dbms_stats.get_prefs('AUTO_TASK_STATUS') from dual;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note `statistics feedback used for this statement` implies that [statistics feedback](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/statistics-feedback-formerly-cardinality-feedback) was used for this query. With statistics feedback, Oracle can find statistics estimate mistakes on the first run and then improve the numbers on subsequent runs. Unfortunately, there are are rare times when improving statistics makes a query run worse. You may want to either disable this feature or try to significantly improve your initial statistics gathering to avoid bad statistics in the first place.

The least intrusive way to fix this problem is to add a hint that disables statistics feedback for your query. Without access to your precise configuration, I can only guess, but I think that one of these two hints should disable the statistics feedback:

```
/*+ opt_param('_optimizer_use_feedback' 'false') */
/*+ opt_param('optimizer_adaptive_statistics' 'false') */
```

While statistics feedback sounds like a good idea to me, apparently Oracle itself does not have much confidence in the feature, since the value still defaults to FALSE in 23c. You generally do NOT want to change a system parameter based on one bad query, but in this case you might want to consider changing OPTIMIZER_ADAPTIVE_STATISTICS back to FALSE for the entire database.

For another approach to solving this problem, you might want to consider removing the parameter `Method_Opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1'` from your statistics gathering call. That value effectively disables all histograms, which may be reason the statistics were bad in the first place. The default parameter value may gather useful histograms that avoid the problem entirely.

---

Since this problem is still happening intermittently, a different tuning technique may be called for. Ideally, we want to find the one bad feature that causes bad plans and fix it. But maybe you have multiple adaptive reoptimization features working against you. Instead of playing whack-a-mole with a few precise hints, this query might call for completely fixing the plan to a specific version.

There are multiple ways to fix an execution plan, like SQL plan baselines and SQL profiles. But since you have access to the query, one simple way is to find a complete list of SQL hints through `dbms_xplan.display(format => 'outline')`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602680/409172) for a full example.

Comment: Hey, I checked both the ways, but nothing seems to be working, so first I ran query with hint for disabling statistic feedback and the query was still running slow. 

Later I tried to gather plan by removing parameter **Method_Opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1'**, after doing this when I ran query its execution was slow even for first run. 

Is there anything else which can be checked?

Comment: @Rudra Try disabling the setting at the session level and clearing any possible execution plan from the cache. For example, in the session, run `alter session set optimizer_adaptive_statistics=false;`, then `alter system flush buffer cache;`, and then run your query tests. Also, double-check your query hints to ensure they are written exactly right. You should see a "Hint Report" in the execution plan that warns you if the hints have a syntax error. If none of that works, maybe try disabling the parameter at the database level, at least temporarily.

Comment: If none of that works, you can always copy the hints from the good plan and force them onto the bad plan. It's ugly, but it should work. In the `format` parameter of `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY*`, add the string ` +outline`, and then the execution plan will generate a set of hints that should keep the plan static if you hard code all of the hints into the query.

Comment: Hey, I checked both the mentioned hints again and it seems that they are working in some runs for same SQL query but not always. Not understanding why, it is not working for few runs, could you please suggest anything for such case where hints aren't working consistently? Thanks a lot for your help, all the suggestions were informative and up to the point :-)